# Capacitor charging

Tags: voltage, resistance

I am stuck at this question.
A battery of 9 V charges a capacitor of 47 uF through a resistor.
What resistor value needs to be used to obtain a voltage across the
capacitor of 8 V when 10 seconds have elapsed? You will need to
obtain the standard equation for the voltage across the capacitor
charging in this circuit configuration. You must show the theoretical
calculations you did to get the result.

I have done some calculations but I seem to be getting the wrong answer.

here is my working out
10 s. =10,000mS.
X = t/RC, Vr
= 9/eᶺx 
= 9-8 
= 1,
eᶺx 
= 9, X
= 2.197 
= 10,000/(R*47), 2.197
= 213/R, 2.197R
= 213, R
= 96.8Kohms

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same answer here.

With the capacitor charge equation:
$$V(t) = V_f(1 - e^{-t/\tau})$$

$$8 = 9(1 - e^{-10/\tau})$$

$$0.1111 = e^{-10/\tau}$$

$$ln(0.1111) = -10/\tau$$

$$\tau = 4.55 s$$

$$R = \dfrac{4.55}{4.7e-6} =  96.8 K$$

Here's a schematic and plot:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkGvpv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Answer (score 1):

TisteAndii has already provided an answer. This answer just gives you some "sanity check" rules that you can calculate in your head to confirm your answer for future calculations.

The time constant of an RC circuit is given by  \$ \tau = RC \$.

- After \$ \tau \$ s the capacitor will have charged to 63% of the supply voltage.
- After \$ 3 \tau \$ s the capacitor will have charged to 95% of supply voltage.
- After \$ 5 \tau \$ s the capacitor will have charged to 99% of supply voltage.

In your problem, 8 V is 8/9 of the 9 V supply voltage = 89% charged. This is somewhere between \$1\tau\$ and \$3\tau\$ but closer to the latter. Let's use \$2.5\tau\$. Therefore:

$$ 2.5 \tau = 2.5 RC = 10$$
$$ R = \frac {10}{2.5C} = \frac {4}{C} = \frac {4}{47 \mu} < 100~k\Omega$$

This agrees well with your calculation.

Comment: Just a minor point that doesn't need to be in my answer: SI units designate "k" for kilo and "K" for kelvin (as in temperature). Capitals matter. ;^)